# How to zoom-in on a particular latitude and longitude. Whenever we pinch zoom in-out then pin is dislocated slightly

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, pinchzoom

Whenever we try to zoom-in or zoom-out on a particular location (lat,long) then it never sticks to that location and shifts slightly here and there. We want to achieve similar functionality that Zomato, Uber and Ola has achieved. Seems like its working in native and android only but not for react native.